# How do you change the style of the Android popupKeyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, styles

I'm using an Android custom keyboard with a few pop-up keyboards on certain keys like so:

```
 <Key
        android:codes="-16"
        android:keyLabel="π"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/symbol_popup"/>
```

The problem is that I can't seem to get the style of the popup keyboard to match that of the parent keyboard.  Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image]

As you can see, I've styled the soft keyboard just fine but how do I get those styles applied to the pop-up keyboard?

Here is the XML for the main keyboard styles:

```
 <style name="keyboard_1_style">
    <item name="android:keyBackground">@color/darkGray</item>
    <item name="android:keyTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/darkGray</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    <item name="android:keyPreviewLayout">@layout/keypreviewlayout</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: did you get any solution please post your answer

Answer (score 1):

add  android:popupLayout="@layout/word_bar" in your xml attribute  **android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView**.

**word_bar.xml** must contain also a **android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView** attribute that have the style you want to customize